# Media query is not applying properly on CSS grid?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to applying media for a device whose min-width is 501px and max-width 768px under CSS grid.

Below is the html and CSS code which i have written in single. Media query is work fine for small device(i.e. max-width: 500px) but not working for medium device.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header header header header"
        "content content content sidebar"
        "box-1 box-2 box-3 box-4"
        "footer footer footer footer";
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.header,
.content,
.sidebar,
.box-1,
.box-2,
.box-3,
.box-4,
.footer {
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
}

.content {
    grid-area: content;
}

.sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
}

.box-1 {
    grid-area: box-1;
}

.box-2 {
    grid-area: box-2;
}

.box-3 {
    grid-area: box-3;
}

.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        grid-template-areas:
            "header header"
            "content sidebar"
            "box-1 box-1"
            "box-2 box-2"
            "box-3 box-3"
            "box-4 box-4"
            "footer";
    }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .container {
        grid-template-areas:
            "header"
            "content"
            "sidebar"
            "box-1"
            "box-2"
            "box-3"
            "box-4"
            "footer";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header class="header">
        <h1>My Website</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="content">
        <h3>Welcome To My Site</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo suscipit
            reprehenderit aperiam repudiandae voluptatibus, expedita ex temporibus
            eos et mollitia velit vel molestias sint dolore at doloremque neque
            minima optio ad tempore quisquam perferendis esse non. Aliquam illum
            doloremque architecto! Rem voluptas at sunt sed enim eius laborum
            dolores quaerat?
        </p>
    </section>
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Some Company</li>
            <li>50 Main st, Boston MA</li>
            <li>something@something.com</li>
            <li>555-555-5555</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <div class="box-1">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores
            quisquam at veritatis a labore quod illo dolorem fugiat quas
            repellendus omnis odio eligendi ab, dolor necessitatibus, saepe
            aliquid quaerat aperiam.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores
            quisquam at veritatis a labore quod illo dolorem fugiat quas
            repellendus omnis odio eligendi ab, dolor necessitatibus, saepe
            aliquid quaerat aperiam.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-3">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores
            quisquam at veritatis a labore quod illo dolorem fugiat quas
            repellendus omnis odio eligendi ab, dolor necessitatibus, saepe
            aliquid quaerat aperiam.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-4">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores
            quisquam at veritatis a labore quod illo dolorem fugiat quas
            repellendus omnis odio eligendi ab, dolor necessitatibus, saepe
            aliquid quaerat aperiam.
        </p>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

I wanted to take 2 column for each box when min-width is 501px and max-width 768px.

It's taking 1 column when max-width: 500px but not when i write min-width is 501px and max-width 768px

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete unnecessary elements from your `@media (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 768px)`:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    background-color: lightpink;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header header header header"
        "content content content sidebar"
        "box-1 box-2 box-3 box-4"
        "footer footer footer footer";
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.header,
.content,
.sidebar,
.box-1,
.box-2,
.box-3,
.box-4,
.footer {
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
}

.content {
    grid-area: content;
}

.sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
}

.box-1 {
    grid-area: box-1;
}

.box-2 {
    grid-area: box-2;
}

.box-3 {
    grid-area: box-3;
}

.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        background-color: lightgreen;
        grid-template-areas:
            "header"
            "content"
            "sidebar"
            "box-1"
            "box-2"
            "box-3"
            "box-4"
            "footer";
    }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .container {
        background-color: orange;
        grid-template-areas:
            "header"
            "content"
            "sidebar"
            "box-1"
            "box-2"
            "box-3"
            "box-4"
            "footer";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      <h1>My Website</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="content">
      <h3>Welcome To My Site</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo suscipit
        reprehenderit aperiam repudiandae voluptatibus, expedita ex temporibus
        eos et mollitia velit vel molestias sint dolore at doloremque neque
        minima optio ad tempore quisquam perferendis esse non. Aliquam illum
        doloremque architecto! Rem voluptas at sunt sed enim eius laborum
        dolores quaerat?
      </p>
    </section>
    <aside class="sidebar">
      <h3>Contact Us</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Some Company</li>
        <li>50 Main st, Boston MA</li>
        <li>something@something.com</li>
        <li>555-555-5555</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <div class="box-1">
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores
        quisquam at veritatis a labore quod illo dolorem fugiat quas
        repellendus omnis odio eligendi ab, dolor necessitatibus, saepe
        aliquid quaerat aperiam.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores
        quisquam at veritatis a labore quod illo dolorem fugiat quas
        repellendus omnis odio eligendi ab, dolor necessitatibus, saepe
        aliquid quaerat aperiam.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-3">
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores
        quisquam at veritatis a labore quod illo dolorem fugiat quas
        repellendus omnis odio eligendi ab, dolor necessitatibus, saepe
        aliquid quaerat aperiam.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-4">
      <h3>Heading</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores
        quisquam at veritatis a labore quod illo dolorem fugiat quas
        repellendus omnis odio eligendi ab, dolor necessitatibus, saepe
        aliquid quaerat aperiam.
      </p>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <p>Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: grid;` every time

You forgot to create `.box-4 { grid-area: box-4; }`

```css
.header,
.content,
.sidebar,
.box-1,
.box-2,
.box-3,
.box-4,
.footer {
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
}

.content {
    grid-area: content;
}

.sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
}

.box-1 {
    grid-area: box-1;
}

.box-2 {
    grid-area: box-2;
}

.box-3 {
    grid-area: box-3;
}

.box-4 {
    grid-area: box-4;
}

.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    text-align: center;
}


.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header header header header"
        "content content content sidebar"
        "box-1 box-2 box-3 box-4"
        "footer footer footer footer";
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}


@media (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
            "header header"
            "content sidebar"
            "box-1 box-1"
            "box-2 box-2"
            "box-3 box-3"
            "box-4 box-4"
            "footer footer";
    }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
            "header"
            "content"
            "sidebar"
            "box-1"
            "box-2"
            "box-3"
            "box-4"
            "footer";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header class="header">
        <h1>My Website</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="content">
        <h3>Welcome To My Site</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo suscipit
            reprehenderit aperiam repudiandae voluptatibus, expedita ex temporibus
            eos et mollitia velit vel molestias sint dolore at doloremque neque
            minima optio ad tempore quisquam perferendis esse non. Aliquam illum
            doloremque architecto! Rem voluptas at sunt sed enim eius laborum
            dolores quaerat?
        </p>
    </section>
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Some Company</li>
            <li>50 Main st, Boston MA</li>
            <li>something@something.com</li>
            <li>555-555-5555</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <div class="box-1">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores
            quisquam at veritatis a labore quod illo dolorem fugiat quas
            repellendus omnis odio eligendi ab, dolor necessitatibus, saepe
            aliquid quaerat aperiam.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores
            quisquam at veritatis a labore quod illo dolorem fugiat quas
            repellendus omnis odio eligendi ab, dolor necessitatibus, saepe
            aliquid quaerat aperiam.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-3">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores
            quisquam at veritatis a labore quod illo dolorem fugiat quas
            repellendus omnis odio eligendi ab, dolor necessitatibus, saepe
            aliquid quaerat aperiam.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-4">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores
            quisquam at veritatis a labore quod illo dolorem fugiat quas
            repellendus omnis odio eligendi ab, dolor necessitatibus, saepe
            aliquid quaerat aperiam.
        </p>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```